Python/Django Dynamic Form creation
I have an html page, which have dropdown field. I had load dropdown values from DB.
Now selecting dropdown, the required fields related to value may be load, which has been described in 1 DB Table. so how is it possible?
I have done like this...
class VenDocMastForm(forms.ModelForm):
doc_cat = forms.ChoiceField(
label='Document Type*',
choices=[(0, 'SELECT')] + [(dt.doc_type_id, dt.doc_type_desc) for dt in ven_doc_mast.objects.all()],
widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown'})
ven_doc_path = forms.FileField(
label='Upload Document File',
required=False,  # This can be set to True if file upload is mandatory
widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control btn-outline-primary'})
     )


    class Meta:
        model = ven_doc_hdr  # Model used for saving data
        fields = [
            'doc_id',  
            'ven_id', 
            'doc_reg_no', 
            'doc_reg_dt', 
            'doc_last_dt', 
            'doc_reg_cat',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'doc_id': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown', 'placeholder': 'Enter Document Type ID'}),
            'ven_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown', 'placeholder': 'Enter Vendor ID'}),
            'doc_reg_no': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown', 'placeholder': 'Enter Registration Number'}),
            'doc_reg_dt': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown', 'type': 'date'}),
            'doc_last_dt': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown', 'type': 'date'}),
            'doc_reg_cat': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-12 form-control-sm dropdown', 'placeholder': 'Enter Registration Category'}),
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Handle form saving to ven_doc_hdr
        instance = super().save(commit=False)

        # Save ven_doc_dtl entry if file is uploaded
        if self.cleaned_data.get('ven_doc_path'):
            ven_doc_dtl_instance = ven_doc_dtl(
                doc_id=instance.doc_id,
                ven_doc_type_id=instance.doc_id,  # Example: Mapping the document type ID from ven_doc_hdr
                ven_doc_path=self.cleaned_data['ven_doc_path'],
                flag_un_di=0,  # Default value
                entered_mode='I',  # Example, set as per your system
                entered_user='current_user',  # Example, replace with actual user
                entered_ip='127.0.0.1'  # Example, replace with actual IP
            )
            ven_doc_dtl_instance.save()
        
        # If 'doc_cat' is used only for selection, it won't be saved
        # Add any additional logic if necessary
        
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

I have done with html, JavaScript and Views, without using Forms.
Now I want to do it using Forms, so I could make it fully dynamic.
from .forms import VenDocMastForm

def add_ven_doc_mast_view(request):
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #     form = VenDocMastForm(request.POST)
    #     if form.is_valid():
    #         form.save()
    #         return render(request, 'success.html', {'message': 'Record added successfully!'})
    # else:
    form = VenDocMastForm()
    return render(request, 'ven_doc_mast_form.html', {'form': form})


So exactly what are you trying to do, and what is not working?
